# String displayed on Simulink blocks

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a Simulink constant block, which displays, depending on its size, the string containing the constant value (let's say "3.14159"), or the string "-C-".

I don't know how to detect what is exactly displayed on some Simulink block (i.e. "3.14159", or "-C-").

Comment: Programmatically from a matlab file?

Comment: Seems like a borderline [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... some context about why you're trying to do this might help solve the problem.